# Load data from Synchronized Data source to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, data-synchronization, activity

We have a custom object in Sales/Service cloud and I have synchronized those objects in Marketing cloud using Marketing cloud connect.

Now, We want to start a journey when we create a new record in our custom record.

We have created Data Extension with exact same fields as out synchronized custom object because we cant use Synchronized data extension directly into journey builder.

I want to SQL activity to load data from Synchronized data extension to data extension but I am not sure how and where to write this.

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to Automation Studio > Activities and create a new SQL Query.

1. Navigate to Automation Studio > Activities and click `Create Activity`.
2. Select SQL Query
3. Give your query a name
4. Now write your SQL query
5. Select your target data extension
6. Specify your data handling (Add, Update, Overwrite)
7. Run your query (you'll likely want to create an actual automation with a schedule) as running the query will only occur once

Your query will look something like this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM ENT.[your_sychronized_DE]
```

You may need more to this query depending on what `WHERE` statements you need for new records.  Please update/post a new question when you get there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried the same steps but I was using my custom object name rather than Synchronized data source name and I found my mistake. I have changed the DE name and it worked fine.

Comment: Great. If that answers your question-mark it as answered!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the QueryStudio package installed, you can select the Lead_Salesforce synchronized table from the table lookup to see what the field names, field length, and field formats (text, date, email, number) are before creating the data extension to hold information from the synced data extension. It is a hassle to create this manually since one simply cannot copy a synced data extension.